# How to emulate a `(include_subdirs qualified)` structure and how to get subdirectories to find modules in parent directories?

Tags: ocaml, dune

I have the following structure:

```
src/
├─ instructions/
│  ├─ dune
│  ├─ arithmetic.ml
│  ├─ bitwise.ml
│  ├─ ...
├─ dune
├─ base_types.ml
├─ memory.ml
├─ ...
```

Everything in `src` should be a library, but I also want things in `src` to be able to access modules such as `Instructions.Arithmetic`, while modules in `instructions/` should be able to `open Base_types`.

First question, my understanding is that this is something that `(include_subdirs qualified)` aims to do. Is this possible to emulate right now?

Second question, is it possible for modules in `instructions/` to be aware of modules in the parent directory without using `(include_subdirs unqualified)`? or is this a bad structure? I want to have `open Base_types` in `arithmetic.ml`, but I get:

```
Error: Unbound module Base_types
```

Essentially, it seems I want `(include_subdirs unqualified)`, but also need the subdirectories to be their own sub libraries as with `qualified`.

Advice would be greatly appreciated.